# Why doesn't the Stack Exchange store support PayPal?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, shop

I just bought two mugs in the [Stack Exchange Shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/).

It would have been nice to be able to pay with PayPal.

Is there a reason it is not supported?

Credit card companies charge a fee for using the card for international payment, PayPal does not; that's why I'd prefer PayPal.

Comment: Interesting. Actually, I'd be interested in seeing what options they take without having to put in all my details first...

Comment: @Grace: aah, that's why the [meta-tag:shop] tag didn't exist yet... thanks!

Comment: There's a Stack Overflow store?  Can someone edit the question to include the link???

Comment: @Adam [done](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What the krutz? The header image on the page says "Stack Exchange Store", but the URL is `shop.stackexchange.com` (and redirects there from `store.stackexchange.com`)? Looks like we'll need to have a synonym indeed.

Comment: @Grace I thought about it too, being pedantic and all, but was left scratching my head at what Stack Exchange was actually going to call it.  I don't remember if it's been "officially" officially announced or not, so they may still plan on making various changes.  I'd hold off on dealing with tag disambiguation until it's actually linked at the bottom of each page...

Comment: @Hannes how much was the shipping fee?

Comment: Shipping was $14.97 USD

Comment: I've wanted to buy things from the shop for a long time with Paypal, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. I'd definitely buy several tens of dollars' worth of things! I agree, please add this feature.

Comment: @minitech I clarified my answer so you know its from a credible and official source.

Comment: @MichaelPryor: I know, I looked on your Stack Overflow profile to find out - that was just the message that fit best. Sorry. Is this ever going to be a possible consideration someday?

Comment: @minitech probably not. I don't think we'll ever have the volume.

Comment: @MichaelPryor: If 500 people upvote this question, then maybe? :)

Comment: No store anymore so this is [meta-tag:status-not-relevant] :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's an accounting issue. Essentially, taking Paypal as another payment method creates additional overhead that isn't worth it for the volume of sales that we currently have on that store.

-- source: I'm the CFO at Stack Exchange.

Comment: But this could change when thousands of people buy stuff every day?

Comment: @George Sure. If it became worth it, I'd reconsider the hassle tradeoff to getting it set up.  Don't hold your breath though :)

Comment: I'm all for PayPal, since I don't have a credit card.

Comment: Holding breath... :)

Comment: @minitech Uuh... you are looking pretty blue, there!

Comment: I'm surprised the store as a whole has income that would pay for the necessary accounting, Paypal or not.

Answer (score 13):

How about...

[image: StackExchange RepPal]

Trade your reputation for Store/Shop items...All the buying goodness without "bank accounts" or "credit cards" or "money" :)

If this were to be taken seriousy, perhaps your store rep credit is based off recently gained rep. However, it's a [good thing you're not selling Porsche's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) in there...fair use policy?

Comment: hmmm...repcoin?

Comment: @Laura - _Way_ too easy to "farm"

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange currently only accepts credit cards.  However, they are using the Shopify service, which allows multiple payment types, including paypal.

http://www.shopify.com/faq#customer-payment-methods

Stack Exchange will have to create a business paypal account and provide that information to shopify in order to start collecting payments via paypal.  Note, however, that they may have better rates through their current credit card processor than they would through paypal, so there may be an accounting decision here to specifically avoid paypal.

While they used paypal it early on for careers subscriptions, they have since incorporated and have a different business legal and accounting structure.  Their previous paypal accounts may not be usable for business.

Comment: Unless they have a *lot* of sales (which I highly doubt since no one even knew this store existed) paypal should have substantially less fees than processing credit cards directly.

Comment: @Kop You might be surprised at how reasonable it is to accept credit cards these days.

Comment: Well I only see, I have to pay an international payment fee for my credit card which I wouldn't with paypal. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Hannes That's a good point - you should update your question to point out why you would like the paypal option.

Comment: Isn't it more costly not to have PayPal if it means less sales than if paypal was an option?

Comment: @davidsleeps - Depends on how much administrative overhead it adds.