# can we order outside the USA from http://shop.stackexchange.com/

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, shop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find shipping information for the Stack Exchange store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/where-can-i-find-shipping-information-for-the-stack-exchange-store)

I have just saw a stackoverflow mug on http://shop.stackexchange.com/ but I am wondering whether we can order outside the USA from http://shop.stackexchange.com/ or not?

Comment: In the question noted above, shipping appears variable based on the weight (as expected), so you probably won't know for a given item and until you put it in your cart and enter your address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/), which powers the store [can ship to any country in any currency](http://www.shopify.com/faq#countries-and-currencies).  It doesn't appear that stack exchange limits this ability in any way.  :O)

Comment: thanks for the info. and there is this info ***Shipping is calculated automatically during checkout depending on your location and desired method of shipping.*** If I order from Turkey, there is a chance to see an expensive shipping fee, right? Is there are chance to see the shipping fee before purchasing?

Comment: I have **no** idea.  The only other link I found on meta [was this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94311/why-doesnt-the-stack-exchange-store-support-paypal) from a user in Germany.

Comment: hmm, I will ask him how much the shipping fee is. That would be probably the same for me.

Comment: @tugberk there's no way to say. Go place your order, you will see the shipping amount *before* you can confirm your order.