# Is it possible to shop with an international billing address, while having US shipping address?

Tags: support, shop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find shipping information for the Stack Exchange store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/where-can-i-find-shipping-information-for-the-stack-exchange-store)

There are four of us in Israel and we wish to buy stuff from the SE shop. We have a US shipping address and each has an international credit card. However, the billing address is in Israel, of course.

As of now, the shop interface does not allow us to complete the order, because it expects the billing address to be in US, UK, Canada or India.

This is a strange (albeit common) limitation, because no one actually sends anything to the billing address with regard to the particular purchase.

In fact, there are quite a few online shops which do not restrict the billing address, because they recognize it does not matter at all.

My question is this - given that:

- the shipping address in US
- the billing address in Israel
- the credit card is international, successfully used in other online shops (no limitation on the billing address)

how can I buy from the SE online shop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find shipping information for the Stack Exchange store?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/where-can-i-find-shipping-information-for-the-stack-exchange-store) and [Can we order from outside the US](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98023/can-we-order-outside-the-usa-from-http-shop-stackexchange-com)

Comment: I would recommend posting this question directly to the [Shopify support page](http://support.myshopify.com/).  @Sathya, I disagree.  He doesn't want to ship out of US.  This is a billing address != shipping address.

Comment: @M.Tibbits My answer is an example of that. Billing address was not the same as shipping address

Comment: Oh, sorry. That wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Guys, of course you can order from outside the US, but only from UK, Canada or India. Can you show me how to order from France, for instance, even if you have a US shipping address?

Comment: This is a specific question, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can absolutely do this, through the normal procedure.  I think your confusion might come from the fact that those 4 countries are at the top of the list - if you scroll down the list you can select Israel as the billing country

**Top of the Country List:**

[image: Country List]

**Israel selected as billing country with US as shipping country**

[image: Full Page]