# Alternative ways to get SO mug

Tags: support, shop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find shipping information for the Stack Exchange store?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/where-can-i-find-shipping-information-for-the-stack-exchange-store)
>   [can we order outside the USA from shop.stackexchange.com/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98023/can-we-order-outside-the-usa-from-http-shop-stackexchange-com)

Are there any ways to get SO coffee mug in Ukraine?

Ukraine isn't in the list of countries suitable for delivery on Shopify.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd In accepted answer for this question it is said that Shopify ships items worldwide but in fact it isn't.

Comment: You are right, either that answer is outdated or not accurate. See my answer for what I found so far..

Comment: Send me a hundred bucks and I'll get you a mug.  Guaranteed.

Comment: @Won't You want to get "mug-smuggler" badge? 88 bucks for delivery is a little too much, I think.

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko: Hey, my time is worth what I say it is.  If you want to go with these cut rate mug smugglers, fine.  But don't be surprised if you get it and its chipped and has dried coffee in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In the page [*Which countries and currencies are usable with Shopify?*](http://www.shopify.com/faq/which-countries-and-currencies-are-usable-with-shopify) it says:

> Shopify works in **almost** every country and currency. It is dependent on the payment gateway you use.

This means Stack Exchange is using a payment gateway that is not supported in your country.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, there's no way to get terrific mug.

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko Perhaps someone could smuggle it into the Ukraine, past the Internet payment gateway censors.

Comment: @MichaelTodd I think my next question will be "Are there qualified mug-smugglers among SO community?". But it seems to be more suitable for SO Careers, not Meta.