# Why do single-author community wiki answers (or questions?) link to revisions, rather than to the author's profile?

Tags: feature-request, bug, community-wiki, revisions-list, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
>   [Revision history & community wiki links show the same page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37921/revision-history-community-wiki-links-show-the-same-page)

Looking at [a couple answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94347/166870) [I've seen lately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735479/540162), I noticed something peculiar: Community Wiki posts* with only one author have not one, but two different links to the revisions page.

[image: answered-at-{time} and {author-name} links]

Is this entirely necessary? When clicking on the author's name in this case, I entirely would expect to be brought to the author's profile, rather than to the (potentially one-item-long) revisions list.

*(maybe only answers? couldn't find any good single-author CW question references)

Comment: I get tripped up by this all the time, though not just for single-user posts.

Comment: They're community wiki. The point of that is that they can be edited by the community. They're not owned by a single person, and the focus is not on authorship. Thus, it doesn't make sense for them to link to the person's profile like other non-wiki posts.

Comment: That's because the posts *theoretically* do not belong anymore to that user.

Comment: But still, when you see a user's name linked, you naturally expect the link to go to that user's profile. I don't think **anything** will **ever** change that natural assumption in my mind.

Comment: @Bobby: I disagree - I understand the function of CW is meant to transfer ownership to the community, but I'm arguing that until it's actually edited by multiple people (and thus giving the "X revs, X users, XX% {user}" link instead), it's very mentally counter-intuitive for a link on that person's name *not* to point to their profile.